# JPA create entity manager factory for every request?

Tags: java, jpa, jax-rs

First of all I am new to JPA and Jax-rs, i am trying to develop a rest service. So i have created a resource class and annotated it.

```
@Path("/companies")
public class CompanyResource {

private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("test");

@GET
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public List<Company> getCompanies() {
    EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

    return new ArrayList<>();
}

@GET
@Path("{companyId}")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Company getCompany(@PathParam("companyId") int id) {

    return new Company();
}
}
```

From what i have understood about jax-rs for every client request instance of `CompanyResource` will be created, that means every time new `EntityManagerFactory` will be created, which i guess is not a good idea, as i just need it to create entity managers, which could be done with only one instance of it. So what is a proper way to achieve this? Or is it ok to create new instance of this factory for every request?

P.S. i have seen some examples where they use `@Stateless` annotation and inject Entity Manager, but i guess they use `EJB` there(i might be wrong) and i don't want to deep into `EJB` right now.

Comment: Should not instantiate EM or EMF often. Use IDE like Netbeans or Eclispes, and you can create Entire Resfull web service and see how it is modeled https://netbeans.org/kb/71/websvc/rest.html

Comment: is your environment Java EE or SE (the latter would be Tomcat I guess)?

Comment: @francescoforesti Java EE, GlassFish as application server.

Comment: @vels4j i have not seen example of what i asked in the url you provided

Comment: EMF once per application, EM once per request

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you should inject the entitymanager itself (not the factory), and let the container take care of instantiation and scopes. What we usually do is something like

```
@Stateless
@Path("services")
public class MyServices {

  @PersistenceContext
  private EntityManager em;

// ...
```

apart from the `@Stateless` (which imho you should use, there's no need to get deep into EJB for this), it's actually quite simple.